# Can a manager's get_queryset function query across relationships?

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I'm trying to use a custom Manager class to limit the queryset when accessing objects from a model. But I'd like to limit the queryset with fields from a related model, something like

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyManager, self).get_queryset().filter(user__is_active=True)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager()
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

But the `AppRegistry` complains, saying that models aren't loaded yet, which I assume to mean the cross query with `user` in `get_queryset`, even though the `django.contrib.auth` app is being loaded before this app. What's going on?

EDIT: Traceback (see the line where it says `user__groups__name=GROUP_MEMBER`)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/vagrant/members_only/base/models.py", line 255, in <module>
    from base.settings import PAGE_NAME_TO_VIEW
  File "/vagrant/members_only/base/settings.py", line 4, in <module>
    from shb.views import *
  File "/vagrant/members_only/shb/views.py", line 10, in <module>
    from shb.forms import *
  File "/vagrant/members_only/shb/forms.py", line 8, in <module>
    class SHBForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 285, in __new__
    opts.help_texts, opts.error_messages)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 212, in fields_for_model
    formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1970, in formfield
    'queryset': self.rel.to._default_manager.using(db),
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/members_only/roster/models.py", line 51, in get_queryset
    user__groups__name=GROUP_MEMBER
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 697, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1304, in add_q
    clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1332, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1144, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1030, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1367, in names_to_path
    if field.is_relation and not field.related_model:
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 60, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 110, in related_model
    apps.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

EDIT: SHBForm

```
class SHBForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SHB
        fields = (
            'director', # foreignkey to RosterEntry
            ...
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SHBForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['director'].queryset = RosterEntry.objects.get_all_active_members()
        ...
```

Comment: What makes you think it is this code causing that error?

Comment: I'm looking at the traceback for the "Models not loaded" error, and it goes to this line

Comment: Which line? Show the actual traceback.

Comment: There's something in SHBForm which is causing the queryset to be evaluated on startup. Please post the code for that form.

Comment: Doesn't the traceback say that the queryset is being evaluated by `self.rel.to._default_manager.using(db)` and `return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)` in the Django source code?

Comment: Yes, but the question is why. Actually, I think I've spotted it: your `base.settings` is importing your view. You definitely shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: That's another file for something else, not the `project.settings` django settings file

Comment: But it's being imported by base.models. You have the dependency base.models -> base.settings -> shb.views -> shb.forms, and since models are imported at startup it is causing that form query to be executed then, before models are loading. None of this has anything to do with the fact that get_queryset accesses a related model.

Comment: But it's been working this whole time before doing this with the `get_queryset` method. The reason why we need that dependency is because we're using a model to represent a view (because we want pages to have permissions associated with them)